# Deepin panel jumps to extended desktop

Tags: panel, deepin

I am currently using Deepin 20.1 and the problem i have is, that my panel jumps from one screen to another depending on the amount of time i spend working on a particular screen. In my opinion that's nonsense.

Therefore the question is, if anyone does know, how to prevent the panel from jumping to my second monitor?

I could not find any option in the settings and searching for it did not work out either.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it seems like the dock jumps to the other desktop when the cursor is placed on the bottom edge of the specific desktop for a short amount of time.